# Marking employees' names if detecting their time of working shifts are too close

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am designing a formula to warn the time of work shifts of the same employee conflicting. Based on the working schedule on A row to arrange the work shifts of every employee. The general working time is 3 hours. For an example of a picture, Andy in the table has arranged a shift at 2021/10/23 22:00, however, accidentally arranges andy works again at 2021/10/24 01:45, and his previous three hours work times have not been completed, which conflicts, so I hope to design that when his name is marked in the B row, it will be marked as a reminder. According to the picture, I originally designed an index and Match function in the D row to catch The names of employees with conflicting working hours are distinguished by V and X, but it seems that this group of functions cannot be successful. I would like to ask if there is a correct solution to solve it, thank you for your assistance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add helper column:

```
=INDEX(IF(B:B="",,REGEXMATCH(B:B&COUNTIFS(B:B, B:B, ROW(B:B), "<="&ROW(B:B)), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, "×", IF(0.125>IFNA(ABS(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY({1*A:A, B:B},
 "select max(Col1) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"), 
 "offset 1", ),,9^9)), " ")), "offset 1", )-
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY({1*A:A, B:B}, 
 "select max(Col1) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"), 
 "offset 1", ),,9^9)), " "))), 99), TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(B:B)))&ROW(A:A)+1, )))))
```

[image]

you can change ranges to fit your needs just dont change last `ROW(A:A)+1`

Comment: I use the same rows and columns to try this formula but it is not accurate.
https://imgur.com/pFRZ3Zg

Comment: @Kakakarsa can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Sorry for My Late Response, here https://www.sendspace.com/file/ugia71